# In ng-admin: Add editionView to entity without a listView

Tags: ng-admin

Say, you want to edit a singleton, then you do not have a list of objects and hence it would be useful to only offer an `editionView`, but no `listView` for an **ng-admin** entity.

For instance as:

```js
var admin = nga.application("Dashboard");
    admin.baseApiUrl("/some/rest/endpoint/");
var entity = nga.entity("config");

entity.editionView().fields([
    nga.field('settings1'),
    nga.field('settings2')
]);

admin.addEntity(entity);
```

attempting to run this, no menu is rendered for the config entity.

Is there any possibility to get this to work?